# Swapping to increase cache?

Tags: linux, memory, cache, swap

I am using a server with 128 GB RAM. While running some job I see frequent swap usage.

The out put from top

```
top - 05:14:51 up 16:52,  2 users,  load average: 3.99, 5.16, 5.37
Tasks: 760 total,   1 running, 759 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 10.9%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 88.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%
Mem:  132050336k total, 130871212k used,  1179124k free,   387620k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,    64396k used,  4129904k free, 117989588k cached
```

The output from free

```
$ free -g
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           125        124          1          0          0        112
-/+ buffers/cache:         11        113 
Swap:            3          0          3
```

From this I understand only **12GB of memory is currently being used by processes, 113GB is os cache.**
My understanding is memory used by cache is non-essential, and during high memory usages this cache is released and given to processes needing memory.

Yet I see the warning in my monitoring tool `1260 pages were swapped to disk in the previous 15 minute(s)`.
**Does OS swap out pages just to increase file system cache on memory? If so will this affect performance of the system (due to frequent swapping)?**

Comment: Is this a "real" hardware server, only running your linux? Or is it a virtual server hosted by some company, that may be tricking you by "sharing" the 128gb among dozens of other users (who all may think they've got 128gb to play with)

Comment: It is a bare metal (real hardware) server running Centos 6.7 at remote data center

Comment: Are you sure you could allocate memory "_better_", and are you sure you're seeing "_frequent swap usage_"? To my experience, Linux won't swap memory if it's being used while cached memory can be dropped (is unused). It is possible that the swapped memory e.g. belongs to demon processes which were installed but have an empty configuration. So getting this out of the way is actually nice. Either way, you can adjust the behaviour by changing the kernel's so called _swappiness_. You'll find numerous discussions about that on the Web.

Comment: By the way, even your question's title may be wrong, because it implies a root cause and an effect -- and the real question is, what is your machine doing there (you're not telling us). If the swapped data is never used, it's better to keep the whole file system in the cache than wasting RAM for completely unused data.

Comment: @ClassStacker My machine is part of a cluster. In this I could tune various applications to use lesser memory (taking more time to complete), this is what I meant by *better allocation*. This machine is currently running batch processing job.

Comment: @ClassStacker My question is will the system swap memory of an existing program to create space for file system cache? I thought File system cache is non-essential service done only on free memory. Is this correct?